# Solving a quasi- or nonlinear PDE

Tags: differential-equations

Is the following PDE solvable in mathematica 9?[image]

When i solve it, the DSolve command does not do anything.

```
 eqn = y*D[u[x, y], x] + (x^3 + x - u[x, y])*D[u[x, y], y] == u[x, y]^2 + u[x, y];
 sol = DSolve[eqn, u[x, y], {x, y}]
```

Comment: Please include the *Mathematica* code that you are using.

Comment: z := u[x, y]                                                                                                                      
p := D[u[x, y], x]
q := D[u[x, y], y]
eqn = y*p + (x^3 +x-z)*q == z^2 + z;
sol = DSolve[eqn, z, {x, y}]

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly, and take your time to learn how to format your code (short version: four spaces indent, more: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Comment: I think the equation and its Mathematica code are both ok now....please help.....

Comment: MMA 10.3 also DSolve can not solve it.

Comment: There are **[things to do after your question is answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)**. It's a good idea to stay vigilant for some time, better approaches may come later improving over previous replies. Experienced users may point alternatives, caveats or limitations. New users should **test answers before [voting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)** and **wait 24 hours before [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)** the best one. Participation is essential for the site, please come back to do your part today.

Answer (score 1):

Only numerically,and that under **certain circumstances**.

```
eqn = y*D[u[x, y], x] + (x^3 + x - u[x, y])*D[u[x, y], y] == u[x, y]^2 + u[x, y];
sol = NDSolve[{eqn, u[x, 1] == -1/2, u[1, y] == -1/2}, u[x, y], {x, 1, 4}, {y, 1, 4}, PrecisionGoal -> 10, 
 MaxStepSize -> 0.001];

 Plot3D[Evaluate[u[x, y] /. sol], {x, 1, 4}, {y, 1, 4},PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**Example2:**

```
sol2 = With[{eps = 0.01}, 
NDSolve[{y*D[u[x, y], x] + (x^3 + x - u[x, y])*D[u[x, y], y] == 
u[x, y]^2 + u[x, y], u[x, 2] == eps, u[eps, y] == eps}, 
u, {x, eps, 2}, {y, eps, 2}]];
With[{eps = 0.01}, 
Plot3D[Evaluate[u[x, y] /. sol2], {x, eps, 2}, {y, eps, 2}, 
PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

**Example3:**

```
 sol3 = NDSolve[{y*D[u[x, y], x] + (x^3 + x - u[x, y])*D[u[x, y], y] ==
 u[x, y]^2 + u[x, y], u[1, y] == 1, u[x, 1] == 1}, 
 u, {x, 1, 2}, {y, 1, 2}, Method -> "Shooting", 
 PrecisionGoal -> 2]; Plot3D[u[x, y] /. sol3, {x, 1, 2}, {y, 1, 2}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image]

**Maple a little more able to.**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer...How did you come up with the initial (Cauchy) data?

Comment: I throw random  initial data until only works.You can say a brute-force search.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify at least two reasonable boundary conditions, such as equations for u(x,0) and u(0,y) or u(0,0) and u(L,L).

Comment: It does not work now either.